# How to read the ABS_ACTIVE data from CAN bus in android java mobile application?

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio, can-bus, android-automotive

I am trying to read the ABS_ACTIVE  property ID data from the CAN bus using CarPropertyManager and CarSensorManager, but that ABS_ACTIVE property ID is not available in the list.

[VehicileProperty ID  reference link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/VehiclePropertyIds)

in this document they mentioned to put this permission: android.car.permission.CAR_DYNAMICS_STATE.

but this permission is not working.

[my build. gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6ja6.png)

[using libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqaGw.png)

[initialization CarPropertyManager and CarSensorManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwysS.png)

above image is the initialization of CarPropertyManager and CarSensorManager in there from which we will get the  property id's. every property id is coming except ABS_ACTIVE

[ABS_ACTIVE CAN BUS data reading code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9rHe.png)

I am using  [these libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QATsS.png)  but I still do not get the output, so please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the android documentation about ABS_ACTIVE

> ABS is active. The property is protected by the **signature permission**: android.car.permission.CAR_DYNAMICS_STATE.
> Requires android.car.Car.PERMISSION_CAR_DYNAMICS_STATE

ABS_ACTIVE needs signature permission. Here is the citation about signature permission from android docs

> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the user's explicit approval.

So only the apps built by original equipment manufacturer(OEM) and those apps registered with them can access those properties.